# CORS after a long inactivity in the chat

Tags: getstream-io

I have been inactive in the chat for more than an hour since the connection was initialized. After I started sending requests to `getstrem` (receiving messages, for example) and I get an error (I attached a photo). Although `connection` is still active and`event health.check` comes to me. This occurs only after a long inactivity.
What could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. When initializing the connection on my own backend side, I create a token and specify the expiration date for it. If not specified, then by default this value will be null (infinity)

[image]